# How to best distribute python packages with _large_ data dependencies

Tags: python, distribution, pypi

I am working on a new Python package that depends upon many rather large (>20Mb each) data files.  Specifically, the library expects the data files to be in a `data/` directory at run time.

Currently, I have them in a "data" directory as part of the distribution package and have my setup.py script configured to install these files on the user's system via `python setup.py install`.  This works for now, but it seems that it would prevent me from uploading the distribution to PyPI given that the tarball would likely exceed
a few hundred Mb.

As an alternative, I'd like to "host" the files on a remote site so as to be kind to PyPI, and have the files automatically retrieved and installed. Is this possible using the existing Python distribution techniques?  If so, could you please describe how to do this or provide an example?  If it is not possible, what are the best practices for pulling this off?

Any insight you could offer would be most welcome.

Comment: I am looking at the same problem now almost 10 years later. Is this solved using distribution tools or some standard practice? I can also host the files in some remote site but I would also like that to be solved jointly when the package is uploaded to the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org) has a similar situation in the distribution of their corpus data. On my linux distribution, the data is in a separate package, so I did some investigation by installing it with setuptools on Windows.

If you try to use the corpus and you don't have it, nltk asks you to run the downloader function (`nltk.download()`). Internally, it uses a [LazyCorpusLoader](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.util-pysrc.html#LazyCorpusLoader) as a standin for the corpus objects that need the data and then loads the data once it's needed.

Like `sys.path` it searches a number of paths beforehand so that the user can put it wherever they want. You can also modify `nltk.data.path` to add your own location for the data.

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting alternative.  I guess I could simply write a little script called get_data.py that, assuming the module has already been installed, would query module.__file__ and place the data files in the appropriate location based on the path returned.

Comment: Assuming the user running it has write access to the directory.

Comment: Thanks.  Frankly I am surprised one can simply point the package_data requirements in setup.py to a list of URLs.